# Display only a fraction of video using AVPlayer

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, video, avplayer

I have a requirement where I am displaying a media library video (AVAsset) using AVPlayer and updating the current frame in the video using a custom slider in the UI.
However, what I am looking for is how to tie the slider with the video without actually trimming the video. 
I want to show a fraction of video attached to the slider i.e. say I have a video of duration 10 secs. I want the slider to be attached to 3-6 secs, which means if the slider is at start it should show the frame at 3.0 secs in the video and if the slider is at end it should show the frame at 6th sec in the video.

Simply put, to the user it should appear as the video is only of total duration 3 secs.

P.S. There is a lot in the above question, but I've tried my best to simplify my query.

Answer (score 1):

1) Seek to start position:

```
int32_t preferredTimeScale = 600;
CMTime inTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(self.startTime, preferredTimeScale);
[mainPlayer seekToTime:inTime];
```

2) Set a timer:

```
_EndOFRegionCheckTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.10f
                                          target:self
                                        selector:@selector(_checkEndPassedFired)
                                        userInfo:nil
                                         repeats:YES];
```

3) In timer fire event check current position and stop playing if necessary:

```
- (void)_checkEndPassedFired {
    AVPlayerItem *currentItem = mainPlayer.currentItem;
    if ((double)currentItem.currentTime.value/currentItem.currentTime.timescale>self.stopTime)
    {
        [mainPlayer pause];
    }
}
```